# C# webBrowser get elements within a class

Tags: c#

i'm trying to click on a link within a class. it's not possible to search for a tag, id or something like that because the program is refreshing the page till there is a ticket available.

the html code looks like this:

```
<div class="items available">
    <div class="item">
        <a href="link.com">
    </div>
    //more item classes
<div class="items sold">
    <div class="item">
        <a href="link.com">
    </div>
    //more item classes
```

i think that i need the content within "items available", and after that the content of item and there i need to click the a element (there is only one a element). but how can i do this?

this is what i think it needs to do.

```
foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
{
    if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "items available")
    {
        foreach (HtmlElement el2 in //get all elements within items available)
        {
            if (el2.GetAttribute("className") == "item")
            //i think it will get the first item class within items available    
           {
               foreach (HtmlElement el3 in //get all a elements within item)
               {
                    el3.InvokeMember("click");
                    break;
               }

            }
         }
     }
}
```

but is this even possible? i hope so!!

Thanks!!!

Comment: "tickets available"? do you mean "items available"?

Comment: oops, i mean "items available". i will change that haha. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is, when you try to get the divs from the document they are not loaded yet because the process is asynchronous. My advice is to do a web request in c#, in order to get the page and use HtmlAgilityPack for extracting elements from html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use HtmlAgilityPack which is the recommended way of extracting elements from a page.

Install HtmlAgilityPack using Nuget. Below is a sample which may be the starting point for you.

```
HtmlDocument _doc = web.Load(url);
var myClasses = _doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(d => 
    d.Attributes.Contains("items available")
);
```

Then you can loop myClasses collection.